# Report Results From Multiple Pytest Assertions in Single Test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest test which runs multiple assertions. For example:

```
def test_x():
    assert 1 == 1
    assert 2 == 2
    assert 3 == 3
```

I want the report from this test to specifically state that each of these assertions passed.
Because my real use case is a time-sensitive system where each single functional test needs to include multiple assertions, I cannot effectively split the test into multiple tests to achieve this.

Running `pytest --verbose` does not give results for each assertion like I had expected.

And yes, I do need these assertions to give indications even when they have passed. Is this possible with Pytest?

Comment: What is wrong with the default indication?  PyTest reporting that the test passed requires that *all* assertions have succeeded.

Comment: The default indication only signifies that the test passed. It does not signify that each individual assertion in the test passed.
I need to create an artifact showing that each individual assertion passed.

Comment: That means I'm not understanding your flow.  How does your test pass unless each individual assertion has passed?

Comment: Put each assertion in its own test function.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel lets say if we are testing a multiline string output by a function and this test (test_x) wants to assert multiple words in this string. Then reporting those multiple asserts would create a report to show exactly which positions were found and from where it failed. Such report does not require to go back to test output manually scan the whole log messages.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this @vijiboy

Comment: @CHINTANVADGAMA i think we touched the place which requires proposing new feature for the test framework and pull requests